# Is there a standard way to name functions which returns another function?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I have a function that takes a string and a list, and returns a function that toggles the string in/out of the list. So if the function gets called twice, the string will not appear in the list, but calling it once, the string will be in the list.

Is there some standard convention (like callback/handler) for a function that generates another function? I'm working with JavaScript.

Thanks.

Code below:

```
function wrappedToggleGenerator(id, list) {
    return function (flag) {
        if (flag) {
            // Clear the list if flag is true
            list.splice(0, list.length);
        }
        if (list.indexOf(id) == -1) {
            list.push(id);
        }
        else if (list.indexOf(id) != -1) {
            list.splice(list.indexOf(id), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have added my code. Thanks for the suggestions, I think I will prefix function generators with "wrapped".

Comment: This might provide some direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368830/how-to-name-factory-like-methods

Answer (score 1):

coding conventions are defined by the project owners, based on some best practices. Its up to you to decide, which conventions you want to follow.

It may be beneficial to have some meaningful name to the method which also includes return value type, but you may as well have a good documentation in place.

In any case, you might want to read on the Hungarian notiation i fyou want to include indicators of intended use to method names.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation